# Pass parameters to element query as array - in PHP

Tags: query, element

In Twig, we can do this like this:

```
craft.entries({
    id: 11,
    relatedTo: 22,
})
```

But in PHP code, this does not work:

```
\craft\elements\Entry::find(
            [
                'id' => 11,
                'relatedTo' => 22,
            ],
        )
```

I think that only way would be loop through array and apply to initial query object each array position as element query method. Or maybe am I wrong?

I checked Craft source code and in file `base/Element.php`, in method `find()` there is no param to pass array of element query methods into.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Element::find()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#method-find) method does not take any parameters, it just serves as the factory method for the appropriate element query for the given element type (for example, [`Entry::find()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-entry.html#method-find) returns an [EntryQuery](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-db-entryquery.html)). You can chain additional methods to the query afterwards:

```php
use craft\elements\Entry;

$query = Entry::find()->id(11)->relatedTo(22);
$results = $query->all();
```

See [Element Queries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html) and [Querying Entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#querying-entries) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it's a twig feature in Craft. If I remember correctly it's done in the CraftVariable and look something like this under the hood:

```php
use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;

$query = Entry::find();
Craft::configure($query, $criteria);
return $query;
```

Where the `$criteria` is the "query config".

**Edit:**
Some references for you.

- [Craft Variable soruce code](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/86dcff6444f0bda0ca56af2fd83d4e4cbcddeeb6/src/web/twig/variables/CraftVariable.php#L240)
- [Yii's configure method](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-baseyii#configure()-detail)